# How I can do a correct triangulation from two views when I don't know the intrinsic matrix?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, triangulation, slam

I want to triangulate some 3D keypoints from 2D keypoints in two views. I use the findEssentialMat() and recoverPose() with opencv. I found when I change the intrinsic matrix, the R and t are also changed. It leads to turn toward a wrong direction in second camera coordination. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean by "when I change the intrinsic matrix".
The decomposing of essential matrix usually has 4 possible solutions. If you provide the corresponding points in two images, recoverPose() will automatically  select the right pose by doing cheirality check. Of course, you can do the cheirality check on your own (the cheirality check means that the triangulated 3D points should have positive depth).